# Best way to work with ng-model Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Let's say I have an application with a login, and a home page once the user is logged in. When I login for the first time it redirects to the home page. When I logout it redirects me to the login with the username and password which I previously typed.

I'm well aware this is how the ng-model binding works. But imagine tons of pages with inputs. Once the user logs out, is it good practice to do a reset of all the models inside the angular services?

Let me type another example: I have a page to create a student. Once the student has been created the input still has the value from the model. Is it a good practice to reset the student service after creating the student? Can someone suggest a better way? I personally don't like this approach since I have to write more code.

```
app.factory('createStudentService', function(createStudentService)
{
    var service = {};

    service.studenName = null;
    service.studenID = null;

    return service;
}

app.controller('createStudenCtrl', ['createStudentService', function(createStudentService)
{
      $scope.createStudenService = createStudentService;
}]);
```

and in the view something like

```
<input ng-model="createStudenService.studentName">
```

it's the not the whole view but you get the idea

Comment: you could just create a property, e.g. `student`, inside the service to hold the whole object. Then bind `ng-model="createStudenService.student.studentName`. If you want to reset the student at the end, just set `createStudenService.student = {}`.

Comment: Exactly! That means that the accountService (the one that logs out) has to have a createStudentService dependency, right? So imagine, let's say 20 pages similar to Create Student. Would the accountService has to have the 20 services dependencies for each page in order to do something like serviceN.property = null ?

Comment: Yes, quite possibly, depending on how your application is structured, and where all that data is used. To be honest, if you really need to wipe everything on log out, just reloading the whole page isn't necessarily a bad option

Comment: What if you stuck everything in a value - which is just an object - and have a property for each service (object) which has the properties you are storing and want to reset? That way you only have to inject a single reference to the value and you can clear service specific properties as needed.